# Gutenberg meta information is saved as HTML comment in post_content field

Tags: wordpress, gutenberg-blocks

I am very new to Gutenberg and just started learning block development. Today I have tried to create a meta field taking references of [this](https://riad.blog/2017/10/16/one-thousand-and-one-way-to-extend-gutenberg-today/) and [this](https://smartcatdesign.net/articles/building-gutenberg-blocks-guide/).

This is how I registered the meta field for my custom post type:

```
function gb_meta_box_init() {
    register_meta( 'ss_event', 'event_hosted_by', array(
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'single'       => true,
    ) );
}

add_action( 'init', 'gb_meta_box_init' );
```

**Block registration:**

```
const { __ } = wp.i18n;
const { registerBlockType } = wp.blocks;
const { RichText } = wp.editor;

registerBlockType( 'ss-events/event-info', {
    title: __( 'Event Info' ),
    icon: 'welcome-view-site',
    category: 'common',
    keywords: [],

    attributes: {
        ev_date:{
            type: 'array',
            source: 'children',
            selector: '.event-date',
        },
        ev_time: {
            type: 'array',
            source: 'children',
            selector: '.event-time',
        },
        venue: {
            type: 'array',
            source: 'children',
            selector: '.event-venue',
        },
        ev_host: {
            type: 'string',
            meta: 'event_hosted_by',
        },
    },

    edit: function( props ) {

        /* define variables */
        let ev_date   = props.attributes.ev_date;
        let venue     = props.attributes.venue;
        let ev_time   = props.attributes.ev_time;
        let host      = props.attributes.ev_host;

        /* define functions */
        function onChangeEventDate( content ) {
            props.setAttributes( { ev_date: content } );
        }

        function onChangeEventTime( content ) {
            props.setAttributes( { ev_time: content } );
        }

        function onChangeVenue( content ) {
            props.setAttributes( { venue: content } );
        }

        function onChangeHost( content ) {
            props.setAttributes( { ev_host: content } );
        }


        return (
            <div id="ss-event-info">
                <h2>Event Information</h2>

                <div>
                    <label><b>Event Date</b></label>
                    <RichText
                        tagName="p"
                        className="event-date"
                        value={ ev_date }
                        onChange={ onChangeEventDate }
                        role="textbox"
                        aria-multiline="false"
                    />
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label>Event Time</label>
                    <RichText
                        tagName="p"
                        className="event-time"
                        value={ ev_time }
                        onChange={ onChangeEventTime }
                        role="textbox"
                        aria-multiline="false"
                    />
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label>Venue</label>
                    <RichText
                        tagName="p"
                        className="event-venue"
                        value={ venue }
                        onChange={ onChangeVenue }
                        role="textbox"
                        aria-multiline="false"
                    />
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label>Hosted by (this is defined as meta)</label>
                    <RichText
                        tagName="p"
                        className="event-host"
                        value={ host }
                        onChange={ onChangeHost }
                        role="textbox"
                        aria-multiline="false"
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    },

    save: function() {
        return null;
    },
} );
```

When I saved the post and checked the the content of `post_content` field, the value I see there is like this:

```
<!-- wp:ss-events/event-info {"ev_host":["Dipankar Ghosh and Subrata Sarkar"]} -->
<div class="wp-block-ss-events-event-info"><div class="event-teaser">Travel Talk is an event where people come and share their experiences of their trips. It helps others to know more about a place.</div><div class="event-date">September 09, 2018</div><div class="event-time">4.30 PM to 8.30 PM</div><div class="event-venue">PRC Uttarpara, 1st floor</div><div class="event-nature">Travel Talk</div><div class="event-org">Uttarpara Tourists' Association</div></div>
<!-- /wp:ss-events/event-info -->
```

The meta information is saved but as an HTML comment.

```
<!-- wp:ss-events/event-info {"ev_host":["Dipankar Ghosh and Subrata
Sarkar"]} -->
```

Then I went on and tried REST API to see how the JSON looks like. As predicted, since the data was saved as HTML comment, it did not have any `meta` key in it.

Here is the JSON output (without any `meta` key) of `http://local.subratasarkar.com/wp-json/wp/v2/ss_event/654`

```
{
    "id": 654,
    "date": "2018-09-04T18:32:44",
    "date_gmt": "2018-09-04T13:02:44",
    "guid": {
        "rendered": "http:\/\/local.subratasarkar.com\/?post_type=ss_event&#038;p=654"
    },
    "modified": "2018-09-04T18:32:44",
    "modified_gmt": "2018-09-04T13:02:44",
    "slug": "travel-talk-2018",
    "status": "publish",
    "type": "ss_event",
    "link": "http:\/\/local.subratasarkar.com\/events\/travel-talk-2018\/",
    "title": {
        "rendered": "Travel Talk 2018"
    },
    "content": {
        "rendered": "<div class=\"wp-block-ss-events-event-info\"><div class=\"event-teaser\">Travel Talk is an event where people come and share their experiences of their trips. It helps others to know more about a place.<\/div><div class=\"event-date\">September 09, 2018<\/div><div class=\"event-time\">4.30 PM to 8.30 PM<\/div><div class=\"event-venue\">PRC Uttarpara, 1st floor<\/div><div class=\"event-nature\">Travel Talk<\/div><div class=\"event-org\">Uttarpara Tourists&#8217; Association<\/div><\/div>\n",
        "protected": false
    },
    "featured_media": 0,
    "parent": 0,
    "template": "",
    "_links": {
        "self": [{
            "href": "http:\/\/local.subratasarkar.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/ss_event\/654"
        }],
        "collection": [{
            "href": "http:\/\/local.subratasarkar.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/ss_event"
        }],
        "about": [{
            "href": "http:\/\/local.subratasarkar.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/types\/ss_event"
        }],
        "wp:attachment": [{
            "href": "http:\/\/local.subratasarkar.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/media?parent=654"
        }],
        "curies": [{
            "name": "wp",
            "href": "https:\/\/api.w.org\/{rel}",
            "templated": true
        }]
    }
}
```

But according to the articles I am referencing (above), it should have the meta key.

And I may be wrong, when I declare a `meta`, does it get saved in `wp_postmeta` table?

### Update

I have just taken the reference of [this](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/block-api/attributes/) and changed the attribute to

```
ev_host: {
   type: 'string',
   source: 'meta',
   meta: 'ev_host',
},
```

and now the meta data is not saving at all! When I come back to edit the post the meta box is empty. I don't see the value saved in the `post_content` field either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your custom post type support 'custom-fields' ?

```
$args = array( //...
'supports' => array( 'editor', 'title', 'revisions', 'page-attributes', 'custom-fields' ),
//...
);
```

I had the same problem and found this solution here : https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/5622.

I can see the meta-property appearing for my posts now, but I get a 403 Forbidden every time I try to save a post :/

I hope this helps :)

EDIT :

I fixed the Forbiden error by removing '_' prefixes from my meta attributes. Meta attributes prefixed with underscore are meant to be private, and I guess that's why it was forbidden.

Comment: I already fixed the issue. Yes, non inclusion of `custom-fields` caused the problem. However, thanks for your reply. I would upvote and mark it as the answer since it will help others as well :)